# How to post a complicated url request using ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax

I want to do a ajax post to a label printing API using string like this, but seems there are syntax error or something wrong, please give to some directions, thanks.

This is for a web API to printing labels.

Below are javascript codes in Asp.Net MVC5 view page.

url like this:

```
var urlString = "http://localhost:3112/PrintService?REQUEST_DATA={
                               "PRINT_REQUEST": {
                                    "PRINT_NAME": "TSC TTP-345 (TEST)",
                                    "LABEL_QTY": 1,
                                    "TEMPLATE_PATH": "WD.LAB",
                                    "PRINT_DATA": [
                                                {
                                                    "storage": "",
                                                    "SPEC": "",
                                                    "ITEM": "",
                                                    "QTY": "500",
                                                    "DEMAND": "0",
                                                    "EXP_DATE1": "2021-05-21",
                                                    "EXP_DATE2": "2021-05-21",
                                                    "ALLERGENS": "",
                                                    "WD_DATE": "2019-10-29 23:59:59",
                                                    "WD_USER": "TEST",
                                                    "WD_USER_NAME": "TEST",
                                                    "TCI_LOTNO": "20190522",
                                                    "SHOP_ORDER": "",
                                                    "SHOP_ORDER_ITEM": "",
                                                    "SHOP_ORDER_DESC": "",
                                                    "SPLIT_SFC_COUNT": "",
                                                    "SUP_LOTNO": "",
                                                    "REPRINT": null,
                                                    "PACKCOUNT": "",
                                                    "SFC": "",
                                                    "WEIGHT": "",
                                                    "PCS": "",
                                                    "SKIN_WEIGHT": -500
                                                }
                                            ]
                                         }
                                     }";
```

ajax like this:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: urlString,
            data: {
            },
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (ret) {
                labeldata = ret;
                window.alert("OK");
            },
            error: function (ret) { 
                window.alert(ret);
            }
        })
```

Comment: Why are you passing all data as a query string?, instead of it you can create one  model and pass whole model in controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `encodeURI()`:

```
var url = 'http://localhost:3112/PrintService?REQUEST_DATA={ "PRINT_REQUEST": { "PRINT_NAME": "TSC TTP-345 (TEST)", "LABEL_QTY": 1, "TEMPLATE_PATH": "WD.LAB", "PRINT_DATA": [ { "storage": "", "SPEC": "", "ITEM": "", "QTY": "500", "DEMAND": "0", "EXP_DATE1": "2021-05-21", "EXP_DATE2": "2021-05-21", "ALLERGENS": "", "WD_DATE": "2019-10-29 23:59:59", "WD_USER": "TEST", "WD_USER_NAME": "TEST", "TCI_LOTNO": "20190522", "SHOP_ORDER": "", "SHOP_ORDER_ITEM": "", "SHOP_ORDER_DESC": "", "SPLIT_SFC_COUNT": "", "SUP_LOTNO": "", "REPRINT": null, "PACKCOUNT": "", "SFC": "", "WEIGHT": "", "PCS": "", "SKIN_WEIGHT": -500 } ] } }';
url=encodeURI(url);
console.log(url);
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: {
            },
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (ret) {
                labeldata = ret;
                window.alert("OK");
            },
            error: function (ret) { 
                window.alert(ret);
            }
        })
```

Comment: Thank you, label prints out, but ajax goes to error section and return ret as a [object Object] warning, is there something else I shoud keep an eye on? But it still prints! Thanks!

Comment: Remove dataType:html and see in console

Comment: Access to XMLHttpRequest at url from origin 'http://mes' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Looks like I shoud add some additional header information in ajax? Not really catch it, thanks.

Comment: Yes, you should add  header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` in `PrintService` file.

Answer (score 0):

you can create one modal and you can pass it in controller as below.

```
var url = 'http://localhost:3112/PrintService';

var model = {
                               "PRINT_REQUEST": {
                                    "PRINT_NAME": "TSC TTP-345 (TEST)",
                                    "LABEL_QTY": 1,
                                    "TEMPLATE_PATH": "WD.LAB",
                                    "PRINT_DATA": [
                                                {
                                                    "storage": "",
                                                    "SPEC": "",
                                                    "ITEM": "",
                                                    "QTY": "500",
                                                    "DEMAND": "0",
                                                    "EXP_DATE1": "2021-05-21",
                                                    "EXP_DATE2": "2021-05-21",
                                                    "ALLERGENS": "",
                                                    "WD_DATE": "2019-10-29 23:59:59",
                                                    "WD_USER": "TEST",
                                                    "WD_USER_NAME": "TEST",
                                                    "TCI_LOTNO": "20190522",
                                                    "SHOP_ORDER": "",
                                                    "SHOP_ORDER_ITEM": "",
                                                    "SHOP_ORDER_DESC": "",
                                                    "SPLIT_SFC_COUNT": "",
                                                    "SUP_LOTNO": "",
                                                    "REPRINT": null,
                                                    "PACKCOUNT": "",
                                                    "SFC": "",
                                                    "WEIGHT": "",
                                                    "PCS": "",
                                                    "SKIN_WEIGHT": -500
                                                }
                                           ]
                                         }
                                      };

  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(model),
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (ret) {
            labeldata = ret;
            window.alert("OK");
        },
        error: function (ret) {
            window.alert(ret);
        }
    })
```

in controller side you can pass model like below.

```
public class PRINTDATA
{
    public string storage { get; set; }
    public string SPEC { get; set; }
    public string ITEM { get; set; }
    public string QTY { get; set; }
    public string DEMAND { get; set; }
    public string EXP_DATE1 { get; set; }
    public string EXP_DATE2 { get; set; }
    public string ALLERGENS { get; set; }
    public string WD_DATE { get; set; }
    public string WD_USER { get; set; }
    public string WD_USER_NAME { get; set; }
    public string TCI_LOTNO { get; set; }
    public string SHOP_ORDER { get; set; }
    public string SHOP_ORDER_ITEM { get; set; }
    public string SHOP_ORDER_DESC { get; set; }
    public string SPLIT_SFC_COUNT { get; set; }
    public string SUP_LOTNO { get; set; }
    public object REPRINT { get; set; }
    public string PACKCOUNT { get; set; }
    public string SFC { get; set; }
    public string WEIGHT { get; set; }
    public string PCS { get; set; }
    public int SKIN_WEIGHT { get; set; }
}

public class PRINTREQUEST
{
    public string PRINT_NAME { get; set; }
    public int LABEL_QTY { get; set; }
    public string TEMPLATE_PATH { get; set; }
    public List<PRINTDATA> PRINT_DATA { get; set; }
}

public class Model
{
    public PRINTREQUEST PRINT_REQUEST { get; set; }
}
```

[image: you will get data in controller like this]

Comment: I notice there is a parameter named "REQUEST_DATA=" in my urlString after question mark, so I can ignore this "REQUEST_DATA" within your model design answer? Thanks.

Comment: yes, now you are posting whole model. so you do not need of it.

Comment: Thank you for your MVC concept answer, its clear and helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You should put this string without URL inside data section, you can't use it like this.

Comment: Thanks for your advise, I should try Vishal modi's model design answer later.